# How to use maya calendar as to-do application

Tags: release-freya, calendar, settings

I am using freya.

How to use and configure maya calendar as to-do application.

Answer (score 1):

Maya is currently not designed to support this. According to elementary guidelines it also should not support this: they adhere the principle of apps doing one thing, and doing that in a great way. Calendars are not todo lists, so there are other apps better suited for this purpose. I.e. Go For It is a very nice app for this.